Change of variables for partial differential equations
I'm reading https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0509235 and get confused by a change of variables for partial differential equations.
Suppose I have the following equation
\begin{equation}
\partial_{x_2}^2 D +\partial^2_y e^D=0
\end{equation}
The statement is as follows, if one does the following change of variables
\begin{equation}
y=\rho\partial_\rho V, x_2=\partial_\eta V,e^D=\rho^2
\end{equation}
The non-linear equation could be mapped to a linear equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\rho} \partial_\rho(\rho \partial_\rho V)+\partial_\eta^2V=0
\end{equation}
I tried to follow this procedure but I couldn't get the correct linear equation. Can anyone provide the explicit derivation for me?
